# JFrame code in JavaEditor doesn't compile in Eclipse

Tags: java, jframe

I am at the very beginning of learning about GUIs in Java.
I use two computers - one old Windows computer and one MacBook.
Now, I'm running the default Java Editor on the Windows PC and Eclipse on the Mac.
It worked fine until I got to AWT/Swing with a JFrame etc. How can I quickly and easily just execute the code written in JavaEditor on my Mac in Eclipse?

Can somebody please help me out? I want to be able to just copy and paste the code to Eclipse from JavaEditor and run it. Thank you very much.

I tried creating a new "Interface" file and it didn't compile. Error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer.

Code:

````
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class Integers extends JFrame { 
 // Anfang Attribute  
private JNumberField 
jNumberField1 = new JNumberField(); 
 private JButton 
jButton1 = new JButton();  
private JTextField 
jTextField1 = new JTextField();  
private JNumberField 
jNumberField2 = new JNumberField();  private JNumberField jNumberField3 = new JNumberField();  private JNumberField jNumberField4 = new JNumberField();  private JTextField 
jTextField2 = new JTextField();  private JButton jButton2 = new JButton();  // Ende Attribute   public Integers() {  // Frame-Initialisierung  super();  setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
int frameWidth = 300;  int frameHeight = 300;  setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);  
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2; 
 int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;  
setLocation(x, y);  
setTitle("Integers"); 
 setResizable(false);  
Container cp = getContentPane(); 
 cp.setLayout(null);  // Anfang Komponenten   jNumberField1.setBounds(39, 31, 75, 20);  
jNumberField1.setText(""); 
 cp.add(jNumberField1);   
jButton1.setBounds(192, 184, 75, 25);  
jButton1.setText("addieren");  
jButton1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));  jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  jButton1_ActionPerformed(evt);  }  });  
cp.add(jButton1); 
 jTextField1.setBounds(45, 213, 174, 20);  
cp.add(jTextField1); 
 jNumberField2.setBounds(39, 64, 75, 20); 
 jNumberField2.setText("");  cp.add(jNumberField2);  jNumberField3.setBounds(39, 101, 75, 20);  jNumberField3.setText("");  cp.add(jNumberField3);  jNumberField4.setBounds(40, 137, 75, 20);  jNumberField4.setText("");  cp.add(jNumberField4);  jTextField2.setBounds(40, 3, 198, 20);  cp.add(jTextField2);  jTextField2.setText("Addieren in den ganzen Zahlen");  jButton2.setBounds(182, 136, 75, 25);  
jButton2.setText("alles löschen");  
jButton2.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));  jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
 jButton2_ActionPerformed(evt);  }  }); 
 cp.add(jButton2);  
// Ende Komponenten   
setVisible(true);  } // end of public Integers   // Anfang Methoden   public static void main(String[] args) { 
 new Integers();  } // end of main   public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen  
int x1 = jNumberField1.getInt(); 
 int x2 = jNumberField2.getInt();  
int x3 = jNumberField3.getInt();  
int x4 = jNumberField4.getInt();   
int sum = x1+x2+x3+x4;   jTextField1.setText("Ergebnis: "+sum);  } // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed

public void jButton2_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {  
// TODO hier Quelltext einfügen  
jNumberField1.setInt(0);  
jNumberField2.setInt(0);  
jNumberField3.setInt(0); 
 jNumberField4.setInt(0);  } 
// end of jButton2_ActionPerformed
// Ende Methoden  } // end of class Integers```
````

Comment: What Java code are you writing?  Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can compile, run, and test on our IDE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the question. Is that piece of code sufficient? Thank you!

Comment: Does the compiler give you any errors? You shouldn't need any additional .interface you just compile and run the `Integers.java` file. The way it is formatted here, it would not compile. Is that how your actual file is, or is it an error in the formatting when you pasted it.

Comment: What is `JNumberField` it isn't a standard class in java, are you using a library or did you create the class?

Comment: It is an error in the formatting. I just opened a new "JFrame"-file in JavaEditor and used AWT/Swing. Not sure if that is what you mean... Thanks and kind regards.

Comment: When you try to run the file/program from eclipse it should give you an error. What is the error?

Comment: I posted it in the question.
Error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted your code, and created a dummy `JNumberField` class because it doesn't exist in java. Then it works fine. Your formatting is broken, it has invalid characters and it has important characters after inline comments.

```
import java.awt.*; 

import java.awt.event.*; 

import javax.swing.*; 

import javax.swing.event.*;


public class Integers extends JFrame { 

    // Anfang Attribute 

    private JNumberField 
    jNumberField1 = new JNumberField(); 

    private JButton 
    jButton1 = new JButton(); 

    private JTextField 
    jTextField1 = new JTextField(); 

    private JNumberField 
    jNumberField2 = new JNumberField(); 
    private JNumberField jNumberField3 = new JNumberField(); 
    private JNumberField jNumberField4 = new JNumberField(); 
    private JTextField 
    jTextField2 = new JTextField(); 
    private JButton jButton2 = new JButton(); 
    // Ende Attribute 

    public Integers() { 
        // Frame-Initialisierung 
        super(); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 

        int frameWidth = 300; 
        int frameHeight = 300; 
        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight); 

        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize(); 

        int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2; 

        int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2; 

        setLocation(x, y); 

        setTitle("Integers"); 

        setResizable(false); 

        Container cp = getContentPane(); 

        cp.setLayout(null); 
        // Anfang Komponenten 

        jNumberField1.setBounds(39, 31, 75, 20); 

        jNumberField1.setText(""); 

        cp.add(jNumberField1); 


        jButton1.setBounds(192, 184, 75, 25); 

        jButton1.setText("addieren"); 

        jButton1.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2)); 
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
                jButton1_ActionPerformed(evt); 
            } 
        }); 

        cp.add(jButton1); 

        jTextField1.setBounds(45, 213, 174, 20); 

        cp.add(jTextField1); 

        jNumberField2.setBounds(39, 64, 75, 20); 

        jNumberField2.setText(""); 
        cp.add(jNumberField2); 
        jNumberField3.setBounds(39, 101, 75, 20); 
        jNumberField3.setText(""); 
        cp.add(jNumberField3); 
        jNumberField4.setBounds(40, 137, 75, 20); 
        jNumberField4.setText(""); 
        cp.add(jNumberField4); 
        jTextField2.setBounds(40, 3, 198, 20); 
        cp.add(jTextField2); 
        jTextField2.setText("Addieren in den ganzen Zahlen"); 
        jButton2.setBounds(182, 136, 75, 25); 

        jButton2.setText("alles löschen"); 

        jButton2.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2)); 
        jButton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 

            jButton2_ActionPerformed(evt); 
        }}); 

        cp.add(jButton2); 

        // Ende Komponenten 


        setVisible(true); 
    } // end of public Integers 

    // Anfang Methoden 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Integers(); 
    } // end of main 

    public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         
        // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen 

        int x1 = jNumberField1.getInt(); 

        int x2 = jNumberField2.getInt(); 

        int x3 = jNumberField3.getInt(); 

        int x4 = jNumberField4.getInt(); 


        int sum = x1+x2+x3+x4; 

        jTextField1.setText("Ergebnis: "+sum); 
    } // end of jButton1_ActionPerformed

    public void jButton2_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 

        // TODO hier Quelltext einfügen 

        jNumberField1.setInt(0); 

        jNumberField2.setInt(0); 

        jNumberField3.setInt(0); 

        jNumberField4.setInt(0); 
    } 
    // end of jButton2_ActionPerformed
    // Ende Methoden 
} // end of class Integers
class JNumberField extends JTextField{
    public void setInt( int a){
        setText("" + a);
    }
    
    public int getInt(){
        return Integer.parseInt( getText() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but when I run your code, Eclipse compiles and Java opens another icon in the taskbar, but it vanishes in a matter of seconds with no window open. What am I doing wrong? I opened a new class and pasted your code. Thanks again for your work.

Comment: Edit: When I run it in the Terminal with a TextEditor, it works perfectly. Thanks. But why isn't Eclipse capable of doing that?

Comment: It's really hard to say what is happening with eclipse. Are you sure you're running the class you think you are? The run config should tell you what class you're running. You might ask another question. Include the code you're trying to run, and a screenshot of the eclipse interface that shows the run config.

Comment: I tried it again and it finally worked after a few tries and adjustments. Thank you for your brilliant help. If I may ask one final question: On JavaEditor I can seamlessly use a graphical menu, where I can design a JFrame with Buttons etc. by dragging the buttons onto a UI. On Eclipse, I seemingly have to do coding manually. Is there a graphical way on Eclipse too? I hope that made sense...

Comment: @complexlogarithm Maybe [this](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) though I haven't tried it. (I don't use eclipse much.)